# background issue with stellar.js

Tags: css, html, background, parallax

I have problems to visualize the background-cover while using stellar.js
I have 4 total divs and I don't understand why the background of the first 3 div's doesn't appear, instead the last one works correctly.
this is the website: http://www.maqrollexperience.com/ivanminutillo/
thanks to all
Ivan

Comment: can you include your relevant code and not just a link to your website?